# Links in pages won't load using Ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using a script for Ajax from Dynamic Drive on my site to load content into my div. It has worked great for me until I created a page where I want links. For some reason I am finding that if I create a page with a single link, the page will not load. I can click on it all I want and the page still will not load. If I have a page that is just purely text content, it loads. Is this a flaw with Ajax, or am I not doing something right? My intention with my site is to have a "Store" section so I can use Amazon Affiliates. I can't even get my page to load even if I have a simple link say pointing to Amazon.com. Unfortunately this Ajax script has been the only successful way I've been able to get my content to load into my main div. For some odd reason links in the links section on my site will appear and that page will load, but not for my "store" page.

My site is: http://veterinarycare.atspace.cc

I'm not asking for a direct code, but just a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

'store.html' gives a 404 Not found... Does this file exist? That is probably your problem... Your links.html page for example has a link to ASPCA and that works fine.

You may also want to look into jQuery, as this is a bit neater for doing ajax and other javascript effects. You could probably get all that javascript mumbo jumbo down to 5 lines or so...
Also remember that your site isn't going to be particularly google friendly with all the content being loaded in via javascript.